# Looking for guidance on setting up Auth0 - Active Directory Federating

Tags: active-directory, auth0, federated-identity

I've been tasked with setting up an SSO solution against an Auth0 instance. Setting up AD as a source to login against was a snap, but I got stuck in the weeds on setting up active directory federation. It looks like federation will allow  users to login to their machines using AD credentials and be already logged into other systems through Auth0:

https://auth0.com/docs/connector/kerberos

Active Directory is pretty weedy, and I'm getting lost in the articles that I have found.  Has anyone seen a good guide for setting up an active directory instance from scratch to do federation? I'll take anything at this point. I'd like to find a way to fully set up an azure VM with all the parts that I need to follow the Auth0 guide.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

For beginner:

- Create free  virtual machine (windows server 2016) in AWS. https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/launch-windows-vm/
- Setting UP active directory - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/02/22/step-by-step-setting-up-active-directory-in-windows-server-2016/
- Creating an Active Directory domain controller - https://auth0.com/docs/connector/test-dc
- Create auth0 AD connection https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/active-directory#create-an-ad-ldap-connection-in-auth0
- Install Auth0 LDAP connector and configure in the virtual machine. https://auth0.com/docs/connector/test-dc#install-and-configure-the-ad-ldap-connector
- Test https://auth0.com/docs/connector/test-dc#test-an-authentication-flow-from-auth0

Additional details:
https://auth0.com/docs/connector

Comment: Okay, I'm going to work through that just in case I missed something but I'm pretty sure I ran through those steps before and was hoping to go one more step. I'm looking at the auto login stuff in https://auth0.com/docs/connector/kerberos. When I tried to run through that code I was refused (there was something about SSO being turned off in the response). I may have misconfigured something, so I'm going through your steps. I think I need to do some ADFS setup and I don't see those steps above. Any further advice?

Comment: I think you  need to whitelist IP address in the connection settings if you are using Kerberos. At first, try without Kerberos and make sure the connection works.

Comment: I set the connection up again, per the instructions (although it seemed to be just the steps in https://auth0.com/docs/connector/test-dc but on AWS, let me know if there were any big changes). Anyway the connection works great, I can test it with their test and log in with my own app. That all seems happy. I white listed my ip but webAuth.client.getSSOData is giving me data with SSO:false.

Comment: Any idea on what I might do next?

Comment: I think you are using an older version of the lock. Auth0 has deprecated the legacy endpoint /user/ssodata (getSSOData). https://auth0.com/docs/migrations/guides/legacy-lock-api-deprecation#am-i-affected-  All the newer tenant has Seamless SSO enabled.  If you have  seamless SSO is enabled, you can safely ignore any message form /ssodata endpoint. @chris